# Assigning image source created dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function:

```
//The img_src is a source of an image 
function myid_templates_editor_create_image(img_src, w, h){ 
    console.log('image source : ' + img_src);
    var body = document.querySelector('body');          
    var image = document.createElement('image');    
    image.id = 'myid_templates_editor_image';   
    image.src = img_src;                
    body.appendChild(image);    
}
```

After the function is invoked, it successfully creates an image element and append it to the body but the image doesnt show. Why? `img_src` has the following value:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAYAAAA+s9J6AAAACXBIW…AkBAAAJAQAkBAAAJAQAEBCAABAQgAACQEAAAkBoAr47wDsSs6PZMN9tgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Comment: `IW…Ak` - looks like a truncated string

Comment: The image tag is <img>, is it not?

Comment: naa.. that value is a base64 encoded value of image.. Which means the argument `img_src` passed in is not the url to an image but the image itself!

Comment: @VijayDev --> So how can I make the image load?

Comment: @Aliyah, I tried to decode that `img_src` value over [here](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter), but it turns up as inavalid/empty image. CAn you make sure that the argument `img_src` value is a valid base64 encoded image value. I also think that value is a bit small. Normally encoded values should have huge # of chanracters

Answer (score 3):

use **`img`** instead of **`image`** in **createElement**

```
function myid_templates_editor_create_image(img_src, w, h){ 
    console.log(img_src);
    var body = document.querySelector('body');          
    var image = document.createElement('img');    
    image.id = 'myid_templates_editor_image';   
    image.src = img_src;                
    body.appendChild(image);    
}
```

Comment: Yep, nice catch! Also its not `ddocument.createElement`, its `document.createElement`

Comment: `ddocument.createElement` is typo